# Multi-Entity Aggregate Best Practices : when to create the first "sub" entity in an Axon Aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon

(Relocating this discussion here from the Axon Forum
https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/multi-entity-aggregate-best-practices-when-to-create-the-first-entity/3827)

The Axon documentation recommends adding new entities to an aggregate through the EventSourcingHandler…

from: [Multi-Entity Aggregates - Axon Reference Guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/modeling/multi-entity-aggregates)

> The creation of the Entity takes place in an event sourcing handler of it’s parent.
> It is thus not possible to have a ‘command handling constructor’ on the entity class as with the aggregate root.

*(sic: note the apostrophe in “it’s” is a typo)*

But when/where do you create the initial entity?

Your GiftCard aggregate starts with no entities. We have a similar model but want an initial entity to be created when the aggregate is created. e.g. imagine if a new GiftCard always came with a “default” GiftCardTransaction.
Where would you do this?

a) in the constructor of the GiftCard:

```
 public GiftCard(IssueCardCommand cmd) {
    ... 
    // problem: never gets replayed!
    transactions.add(new GiftCardTransaction(/*defaults*/)
```

b) in the initializing event handler

```
public void on(CardIssuedEvent evt) {    // initialize aggregate
      // create the first entity
      // gets replayed when the aggregate creation is replayed
     transactions.add(new GiftCardTransaction(/*defaults*/)
}
```

c) in the event handler but by firing the event

```
public void on(CardIssuedEvent evt) {     // initialize aggregate
       // fire the event to create the first entity
      // problem: gets replayed twice: when the aggregate creation is replayed and the subsequent event is replayed!!?
      apply(new CardRedeemedEvent(/*defaults*/);
   }
```

d) same as c but use an annotation to prevent the double replay:

```
public void on(CardIssuedEvent evt) {    // initialize aggregate
      // call a non-replayable method to fire the event
      createFirstEntity();
 }

@DisallowReplay  
public void createFirstEntity() {
      // The replay of this CardRedeemedEvent will create the first entity on replay, 
      // but the replay of the CardIssuedEvent will not, thanks to the @DisallowReplay... right??
      apply(new CardRedeemedEvent(/*defaults*/);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the event sourcing repository the correct answer is b. You should not apply an event in an event sourcing handler. The Event sourcing handler should only update the state of the Aggregate. Every time a new command is handled, all the events with the AggregateId for that Command will be replayed against an empty instance of that Aggregate before the Command handling starts. That is why you should not apply an event in an EventSourcing handler. The creation of the entity is a side effect of the first event. Disallow replay could be used in methods or classes that use the EventHandler annotation and not for EventSourcingHandlers.

Comment: thanks Yvonne, but I'm concerned that option b. relies on the order of the statements in the command. i.e. the command handler method in b. would fire 2 events: the aggregate creation event, _then_ the first entity creation event. This relies on those two firings to be handled in the exact order to ensure the aggregate is initialized before the entity is added. Option c, however, guarantees that the aggregate is initialized. Also, doesn't my quote from the documentation guarantee that I won't get the side-effect even if I _do not_ add any special "disallow" annotation?

Comment: @rhubarb Axon makes sure that the order is preserved. So if the command handler fires 2 events, these events will be replayed in the same order. If you take a look at the event store you can find the aggregateSequenceNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Vaishnavi answered this in the Axon forum:

> Creating the entity should be done using the @EventSourcingHandler, in your example option b. The state changes should happen here, and the first Event Handler should set the Aggregate Identifier. Here’s a reference to the Aggregate documentation.
>
> Hope this helps with the aggregate creation entity.

But I wonder if that doesn't confuse instantiation+addition of an entity from the @EventSourcingHandler for *the event that creates the entity* (which indeed seems correct), with my case where the option b is creating the first entity in the handler for the *event that creates the **Aggregate***

Actually on a careful re-read of the documentation I wonder if c. is not the correct answer:

from: [Command Handlers - Axon Reference Guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/command-handlers)

> Axon will ignore the `apply()` invocation when replaying historic events upon sourcing the given Aggregate

This statement means that my comment in c. about the "problem" of replaying twice is *wrong* (Axon is clever enough to know that an `apply` in an event handler would always result in double-replay so ignores it on replay...?)

So is c. the right answer?

Specifically:
*If you want to create an initial entity in a Multi-Entity Aggregate, then create it in Event(Sourcing)Handler that handles the **Aggregate** creation event*